# Raspberry PI 3 with Funcube Dongle Pro+ SDR does not read the antenna

Tags: wifi, wireless, radio, gnuradio

I am trying to configure my RPi3 into a small receiving ground station. I already have installed the gnuradio, gqrv, gpredict packages. The RPi is connected to an SDR dongle (Funcube Dongle Pro+) with a small antenna attached to it. It does not get any signal in gqrv though - am I missing something? Looked through a few forums and none has any thread even close to this one. Screenshots picturing gqrv setup attached.
Thanks
[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]
[image: Pic3]

Comment: I googled "Funcube Dongle Pro+ SDR" but found most links are out of date.  Could you give us any updated link?

Comment: https://www.hamradio.co.uk/sdr-amsat-uk-funcube/funcube/funcube-dongle-pro-new-pd-4094.php
Here you can find it at the bottom - there are some manuals and factsheets.

Comment: Tks for ref link.   I was surprised that I did not find this link. I did remember one article says the dongle is linux compatible.  But the details of that article is out of date, so I asked you for update.  Just now I read the manual (https://www.hamradio.co.uk/userfiles/file/FCD2ManualV3.pdf) which only refers to Windows, no linux.  Now my questions: (1) Any install guide for Rpi? (2) FunCube (https://funcube.org.uk/) sounds an edu proj for the young.  How come   not that popular?

Comment: And can I assume that (1) you installed the dongle in Rpi stretch/jessie etc similar to the following: ( 
http://webshed.org/wiki/FUNcube-Dongle-Linux ), and (2) the command "$ lsusb" says it is detected?

Comment: And if the dongle works in Win10, but not in stretch9, then it is likely that the dongle driver (automatically installed, I assume) is not that up to date.

Comment: An old thread, but comes up in searches, a FUNcube dongle can be successfully used with a RPi.
If you wish to use as a groundstation for the FUNcube series of satellites, we have everything running in a docker image, the complete source of which is available at:
https://github.com/funcube-dev